# Macbook Pro Mid-2010 Nvidia GT 330M Handle 3 Monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

Before I actually ask anything, here are the specs for of interest:

Computer:  MacBook Pro Mid-2010
Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU   M 520 @ 2.40 GHz 2.40 GHz
HD:  320 GB
RAM:  8 GB
Video/Graphics Card:  Nvidia GT 330M
OS:  Windows 7 Professional
Monitor Resolution(s):  1920 x 1080

Currently, I have two 23 inch LED monitors connected to my computer, one being through the miniport via HDMI adapter, the other being through USB with DisplayLink's Plugable UGA-2K-A USB 2.0 Graphics Adapter, both of which function fine, except for the occasional pixel lag on the monitor hooked up through DisplayLink's USB adapter.

I am not a gamer, so I am not looking for that type of functionality; but I am greedy, and I would love to add a 3rd monitor if it were possible, but I am unsure of what my video card can handle.  My plan would be to buy USB hub and another DisplayLink adapter and hook up the third monitor through that, with the monitor ideally being another 23 inch LED monitor.  With all that being said, I was hoping if someone knew if a)  the Nvidia GT 330M can handle a third monitor and b) in your opinion, is it worth it to even add a third monitor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your displaylink adapter is not depending on the videocard in any way. You can probably add a second displaylink adapter. But performance on the two displaylink monitors will be slow.

You can also look into products like matrox dualview2go, or trippleview2go. Which splits a dvi connection, to more monitors. You then have to use a displayport to DVI adapter, with the Matrox splitter.

The advantage with a dedicated matrox adapter, is that you get no lag. 
The bad is that it's expensive, and sort of bulky to carry in a laptop bag.

Comment: Never heard of the matrox adapter, will have to look into it.  Bulkiness is no problem, I use my laptop more as a desktop nowadays, given my new found love for software engineering.  Thanks for the quick response.  If someone would be kind to up-vote Markus for me, wish reputation carried over between stack exchange sites lol.